# Finding maxima and minima with another method than Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Find all the maxima and minima of
f
(
x,y
) =
x
subject to the constraint
g
(
x,y
) =
y^
2
+
x^
4
−
x^
3
= 0

The lagrange multipliers dont give all the answers. What other method should i use?

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt give all the solutions?  It should, if you do it right.  But it will only give you solutions along the constraining curve, not inside of the entire possible point space being considered for solutions. For solutions not along the constraining curve, you still have to solve $\nabla f = \vec{0}$.

Comment: Okay, sure. Im sure your teacher tasked you with a problem he never taught you how to solve. I believe that.

Comment: I already told you how to solve it. But you dont want to believe it, so there is little more I can do for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is some $y$ such that $g(x,y) \ge 0$ **iff** $x^4 \le x^3$. Furthermore, $x^4 \le x^3 $ **iff** $x \in [0,1]$.
 Hence the problem becomes $\min \{ x | x \in [0,1] \}$ or the
corresponding $\max$ problem.

Comment: I am not sure if i get it, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: $g(x,y) = 0$ **iff** $x^4-x^3 = - y^2$ **iff** $x^4-x^3 \le 0$ **iff** $x^4 \le x^3$ **iff** $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: ah, beauty!!!!!